# if $\sin^2x=\frac{\cos(2a) \cos(2b)}{\cos^2(a+b)}.$ prove ...

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, contest-math

if $$\sin^2x=\frac{\cos(2a) \cos(2b)}{\cos^2(a+b)}.....(1)$$ prove that $$\tan^2{x/2}=\frac{\tan{(\pi/4+a)}}{\tan{(\pi/4+b)}}$$ or $$\tan^2{x/2}=\frac{\tan{(\pi/4-a)}}{\tan{(\pi/4-b)}}$$

---

Let $\tan{x/2}=t$

From $$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$, $$t^2-\frac{2t}{\sin {x}}+1=0$$

By quadratic formula roots are :$$t=\frac{\frac{2}{\sin {x}}+ \sqrt{\frac{4}{\sin^2 {x}}-4}}{2}$$ and its conjugate.

from here we  can substitute the value of  $\sin^2 x$ from  (1) but it is too messy, and i am not able to simplify further. Is there any other elegant approach?

**Source** S.L Loney plane trigonometry

Comment: @Student1058 yes !thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve your question. Therefore I will follow and wait for someone else to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}\sin^2 x&=\frac{\cos(2a) \cos(2b)}{\cos^2(a+b)}\\
&=\frac{\cos[(a+b)+(a-b)] \cos[(a+b)-(a-b)]}{\cos^2(a+b)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2(a+b)\cos^2(a-b)- \sin^2(a+b)\sin^2(a-b)}{\cos^2(a+b)}\\
&=\cos^2(a-b)-\tan^2(a+b)\sin^2(a-b)\\
&=1-\sin^2(a-b)-\tan^2(a+b)\sin^2(a-b)\\
&=1-\sin^2(a-b)[1+\tan^2(a+b)]\\
&=1-\frac{\sin^2(a-b)}{\cos^2(a+b)}\end{align}$

Since $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ , we get $$\cos x=\pm\frac{\sin(a-b)}{\cos(a+b)}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Solve for $t^2$.

Comment: yes i think i get it , ie we use componendo and dividendo  a little simplification yields the result

Comment: Yes yes yes I just realized that. Glad to know I helped.

Comment: very nice proof, i like the way you got $cosx$

Comment: You're welcome.